# How to resolve an Operational Error at /admin/polls/queston/ which says no such column: polls_queston.category_id?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a class Categories in models.py

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, in order to classify questions into categories, I have

```
class Question(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

I have one category named world in views.py

```
def world(request):
    category = Categories.objects.get(name='world')
    latest_questions = category.question_set.all()
    context = {'latest_questions': latest_questions}
    return render(request, 'polls/world.html',context)
```

And, also I have prepared urls for each of four categories: world, technology, screen and sports and after all this when I open ...../admin/polls/question, I get an operational error. What am I supposed to modify here?

Comment: You need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run migrate command in-order to force django to create tables.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then for any change you made on models, don't forget to run these two commands.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```